# Read property from the same class

Tags: c#

In C# if I have this in a class:

```
public int SomeNumber
{
    get { return 6; }
}
```

How can I read (get) that number from a function in the same class if the function receives a variable with the same name? Example:

```
public bool SomeFunction(int SomeNumber)
{
    check if SomeNumber (the one passed to this function) == SomeNumber (the one from the public int)
}
```

Comment: if function is static - you can't access this property without creating the class instance, otherwise this property can be accessed from everywhere, even from the different classes which have an instance of currrent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the other suggestions do work well (and adhere to easier to read/maintain code), they don't directly answer your question. Given a class

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public int SomeNumber { get { return 6; } }
  ...
```

And a function with a parameter passed in

```
  public void SomeMethod(int SomeNumber)
  {
    // Your code here...
```

You can access the passed in parameter and property like so:

```
    if (SomeNumber > this.SomeNumber)
    {
      // Your results here
```

The distinction is that if you refer to just the variable name, it will use the variable from the same scope, i.e. the passed in variable. If you specify use "this." then you always get the class member.

Note: This does not work with Static classes, as there is no instance of the class. (Can't use "this.whatever") and you will be stuck. There are many coding Standards out there and some of them states that it is best practice to use the form "myVariable" for method parameters, "MyVariable" for property names, and _myVariable for property backing stores, to easily distinguish between them in your code.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm doing now. Unfortunately I can't rename anything as these are all interface methods and properties from a 3rd party that I am implementing.

Answer (score 7):

You would simply invoke the property get in the method:

```
 public void MyMethod()
 {
      var someNum = SomeNumber; // basically, var somNum = this.SomeNumber;
 }
```

EDIT: To clarify with OP's edit:

```
 public void MyMethod(int someNumber) 
 // Change the naming of your parameter so it doesnt clash with the property
 {
       if(someNumber == SomeNumber)
          // Do Stuff
 }
```

Comment: if only function not static :)

Comment: @Samich - Hence the reason MyMethod is a public void not a static public void.

Comment: "This" doesn't work. Do I need something special to access "this"?

Answer (score 3):

Same as if it were a field:

```
public void SomeOtherFunction()
{
    var x = SomeNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FavoriteNumber
{

  public int SomeNumber
  {
    get { return 6; }
  }


  Public int Twelve()
  {
     return SomeNumber*2;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question with more info. Take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Please run this code and you will get it.. Use this operator to refer the class level variale.

```
    public void CheckNumber(int SomeNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SomeNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(this.SomeNumber);
    }
```